# In the webpack-simple Vue.js template, how can I access the Vue app from the console?

Tags: vuejs2, vue.js

I've created a Vue.js app using `vue-cli` with the [webpack-simple template](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple), and it works great.  In the [provided main.js](https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack-simple/blob/master/template/src/main.js), I changed the `new Vue(...` line to `var vm = new Vue(...`, so that I could access the Vue instance from the Chrome Dev Console, but the variable `vm` still shows as undefined.

What is the correct way for me to get a reference to the Vue object so that I can do things like manually generating events in components, or manually modifying data from the console?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try with `window.vm = vm;`

```
var vm  = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

window.vm = vm;
```

And than just type `vm` in console. Your Vue object will be available now.

Comment: Thank you!! Worked like a charm!

Comment: You're welcome, can you please accept answer. Thanks

Comment: Yep, was just waiting the required 15 minutes before it would let me accept :)

Answer (score 1):

Another option is:

1. Do not modify main.js / main.ts generated by vue-cli
2. Install Vue.js devtools (available for Firefox and Chrome)
3. On your Vue-powered website press `F12` (open dev console) and go to `Vue` tab
4. Every component gets assigned to $vmX variable which you can use in the console.

[image]